# Cypress - How to verify data from a PDF file using cypress command

Tags: cypress

Below is my code in cypress. How to print 'pdf' content and verify content using cypress .contains or .eq? when I run the code it prints object{6} but I want to print my pdf file content. I would really appreciate the help.

```
**Plugins/index.js:**

const fs = require('fs')
const pdf = require('pdf-parse')
const path = require('path')

const repoRoot = path.join("C:/Users/XXXXX/Downloads/loginCy-excel")

const parsePdf = async (pdfName) => {
  const pdfPathname = path.join(repoRoot, pdfName)
  let dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync(pdfPathname);
  return await pdf(dataBuffer)
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {
on('task', {
        getPdfContent (pdfName) {
          return parsePdf(pdfName)
        },
      })

}



**cypress spec file has these code:**

it('tests a pdf', () => {
    cy.task('getPdfContent', 'sample.pdf').then(content => {
        cy.log(content)
})
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone struggling with testing PDF files with cypress can refer to these two very good blog posts precisely on this topic:

1. https://filiphric.com/testing-pdf-file-with-cypress
2. https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-pdf/

It wasn't asked in this question, but here is a little addition from me on how to download files (was tested on PDFs) from a URL:

```
cy.request({
        url: '<file url>',
        gzip: false,
        encoding: 'base64',
    }).then((response) => {
        cy.writeFile(
            Cypress.config('downloadsFolder') + '/<name of the file>.pdf',
            response.body,
            { encoding: 'base64' }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

`pdf` method will [return an object](https://gitlab.com/autokent/pdf-parse/-/blob/master/lib/pdf-parse.js#L45), so I guess `cy.log()` can't print it like that. If you want to see what the function gathered in your pdf file, you can stringify the result:

```js
cy
  .log(JSON.stringify(content));
```

If you want to get only text from your pdf, you need to work with `text` property:

```js
cy
  .log(content.text);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @pavelsaman How can I add assertion to verify particular text present in the pdf ? I can't do this:cy.log(content.text).should('have.text', 'Hello') How can I add assertion?

Comment: Read the documentation first https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions

Comment: From the Cypress document you shared I got these assertion. Any thoughts? 
           cy.wrap(content.text).should('have.string', 'Hello World!')                                            
           expect(content.text).to.have.string('Hello world!')

Comment: Do they work as expected? Do they correctly report "no match"?